# Why am I getting "Application does not take parameters" and how do I fix this?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

@TravisBrown [helped me yesterday with an implicit function that returned a Writes[T]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748786/getting-a-play-json-jsvaluewrapper-for-a-class-that-extends-a-trait), which I got working fine, but today I tried to adapt it for another example and got the error on the last line ("Application does not take parameters").  What am I doing wrong?

Please ignore the `toString` methods, they're just there for debugging.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

sealed trait PressureUnit
case object HectoPascalsUnit extends PressureUnit  { override def toString(): String = "(HectoPascalsUnit)" }
case object InchesMercuryUnit extends PressureUnit { override def toString(): String = "(InchesMercuryUnit)" }

case class Pressure(value: Float, unit: PressureUnit)

class SeaLevelPressure(override val value: Float, override val unit: PressureUnit) extends Pressure(value, unit) {
  override def toString(): String = "(SeaLevelPressure value:"+value+" unit:"+unit+")"
}
class StationPressure(override val value: Float, override val unit: PressureUnit) extends Pressure(value, unit) {
  override def toString(): String = "(StationPressure value:"+value+" unit:"+unit+")"
}

object Pressure {
  implicit val pressureWrites: Writes[Pressure] = (
    (__ \ 'value).write[Int] and
      (__ \ 'unit).write[String].contramap[PressureUnit] {
        case HectoPascalsUnit => "hPa"
        case InchesMercuryUnit => "INS"
      }
    )(unlift(Pressure.unapply))  // Error: Application does not take parameters
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to change this:

```
(__ \ 'value.write[Int] and
```

to this:

```
(__ \ 'value.write[Float] and
```

Sorry to bother you!